# How to create an index to avoid sorting step used with DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, postgresql-9.2

```
PostgreSQL 9.2
```

I have the following table (`tbl`):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id   |  mailing_id  |  recipient_id  |  delivery_state_id |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| PK   |   integer    |     integer    |       integer      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, the I created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name
  ON tbl
  USING btree
  (recipient_id);
```

Since, indexes in posgtresql have default sorting, I expected the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id 
FROM tbl
```

can avoid the sort step. But running

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id 
FROM mailing.mailing_recipient mr
```

show me that it can't:

```
 Unique  (cost=1401370.66..1442288.31 rows=145798 width=4) (actual time=9377.410..11388.869 rows=1037472 loops=1) 
   ->  Sort  (cost=1401370.66..1421829.48 rows=8183530 width=4) (actual time=9377.408..10849.160 rows=8183160 loops=1) 
         Sort Key: recipient_id 
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 111968kB 
         ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..126072.30 rows=8183530 width=4) (actual time=0.008..1073.771 rows=8183160 loops=1) 
 Total runtime: 11448.373 ms
```

As you can see, there's still sorting.

***Question***: How can I create the index to avoid sorting step?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you also tried `SELECT recipient_id 
FROM tbl group by recipient_id order by recipient_id`?  Most of the time, any `distinct`, `group by`, or `order by` is going to end up doing a sort, but I agree that the default sorting of the btree index should allow the optimizer to use that to your advantage.

Comment: @SlimsGhost Tried after GordonLinoff's answer. Doesn't work either. I guess postgresql uses indexes for index scans required by the where clause...

Comment: Is recipient_id constrained to NOT NULL?

Comment: Did you run `ANALYZE` after adding the index?

Comment: Ah, if there is no NOT NULL constraint on the column then a regular index is not guaranteed to contain all of the values in the column, as indexes do not include entries for NULLs. If there should not be nulls then alter the column to NOT NULL. You might test "SELECT DISTINCT recipient_id FROM tbl where recipient_id is not null" in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

This surprises me; I would expect Postgres to be smarter than that.  What happens with this version?

```
SELECT recipient_id 
FROM tbl
GROUP BY recipient_id;
```

What version of Postgres are you using?  Postgres introduced index-only scans in version 9.2 (see [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#What_types_of_queries_may_be_satisfied_by_an_index-only_scan.3F)), which might explain the lack of use of the index. I can say that an index scan is used for `distinct` in 9.3.

Here is an explain in 9.3 on a similar query (`select distinct totalprice from orders`):

```
Unique  (cost=0.42..5505.62 rows=2794 width=8)
  ->  Index Only Scan using idx_orders_totalprice on orders  (cost=0.42..5023.16 rows=192983 width=8)"
```

Comment: Doesn't work either `Group ->  Sort -> Sort key: recipient_id `. Maybe I need to create the index in some special way? I re-checked the index existence for the column....

Comment: BTW postgresql uses index when I set `limit` that is not too high. For instance `limit 2000` uses index, but `limit 10000` doesn't.

Comment: @Gordon Does the explain plan still have a sort when the index is used?

Comment: @DavidAldridge . . . I put the explain in.  There is no sort for an index scan.

Comment: Ooh, very interesting. I wonder if this came in 9.2 when the index scan became possible, or in 9.3?

Comment: @DavidAldridge . . . Based on the OP's question, I am guessing this came with 9.3.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So, it's not possible with 9.2?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . Can you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your order by statement matches your indexes **exactly**, including NULLS LAST (or FIRST) in your queries.

[image: Index Definition]
[image: Without Specifying NULLS LAST in ORDER BY Statement]
[image: With Specifying NULLS LAST on each of the ORDER BY Fields]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557